# Does model.fit works in loops?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, time-series

I am trying to apply TimeSeriesSplit from sklearn to a time series model classification problem. The code below works, but I am uncertain of whether does this fit_generator build on previous results or does it just restart the learning?

```
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit()
for tr_index, val_index in tscv.split(X):
    X_tr, X_val = X[tr_index], X[val_index]
    y_tr, y_val = Y[tr_index], Y[val_index]
    generator = TimeseriesGenerator(X_tr, y_tr, length=n_input, batch_size=32)
    history.append(model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=100, validation_data=
    TimeseriesGenerator(X_val, y_val, length=n_input, batch_size=32), verbose=2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of notes:

1. Yes, at every split of X(check to see the default number of splits in TSVC, should be 5), new training and validation sets are created and therefore new training sessions begin. Even if there is only one split, the for loop is made redundant but the code does not fail.
2. `model.fit_generator()` has been deprecated as of TensorFlow 2.1 in favor of `model.fit()`. You may want to opt for the latter.

Update:

You can see in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html) that the number of splits is 5. Therefore you will have 5 different networks, all which start the training from scratch.

> https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html

Comment: @tonywang since you accepted it as solving one, could you please also upvote my answer? It helps both me and others. Thank you.